# Is there a Difference between an Authenticationscheme and an Authenticationprotocol?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, network-protocols

Currently, im working on a small article about the authentication possibilities in Asp .Net Core. Authentication is completely new to me, and i was getting confused, because some sources talk about authenticationschemes, and some about authenticationprotocols. Are there any differences? Or is scheme a synonym for protocol in this case?

e.g.:
in this source, NTLM is described as a scheme:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/understanding-http-authentication

here it's listed as a protocol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication_protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenIDConnect, OAuth, LDAP, etc. are protocols.
Cookie, Bearer (for JWT) are schemes.

An application can use multiple authentication mechanisms (JWT, Cookie) in the same app (for example if it has MVC with Razor views, using cookies and WebAPI using JWT).

i.e.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:8000";

    options.ClientId = "mvc";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";

    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("api1");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
    };
});
```

The scheme is used to determine from which of those providers to use to obtain the user information (such as authentication status, claims etc).

`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]` on a controller or action will use the user data obtained from these JwtBearer Auth provider, where `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookies")]` will use the information obtained from cookie authorization provider.

Comment: To add to this, scheme was a poor naming choice because of how it clashes with the HTTP scheme meaning, but we're stuck with it. It's just a string / key from which to lookup the authentication handler it refers to from the list of all handlers in an application.